# Android code to Access private Google Spreadsheet and insert, update, edit values

Tags: java, android, google-sheets, google-drive-android-api

I know this question will look like so Old.

But I didn't get answer. I want to design app like the user will give their gmail access from Account Manager. I have to create a spread sheet,insert,Update,edit and Delete Value.

I know how to access public spreadsheet. But My app is like it "will create separate spread sheet for each user in their gmail. So i need to access private sheet with out (Email iD and password) or (Auth Key)

Any one know please help to get out from this problem.

Is this not possible also let me know.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/authorizing), when your application requests private data, the request must be authorized by an authenticated user who has access to that data. Unlike with public data that the request doesn't need to be authorized, but does need to be accompanied by an identifier, such as an API key.

So I guess it is not possible to access private sheet without authorization.

You may refer with this SO question: [How to get access to a private spreadsheet from the API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39747381/how-to-get-access-to-a-private-spreadsheet-from-the-api)

Comment: Thank you for your response. If the Document is Published Means I can able to create new Spreadsheet and insert,edit,update it? If you have any sample code means please share . Have a good day